# spring boot angularjs spring data jpa crud-app example get 404 error in eclipse

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data, http-status-code-404, crud

http://websystique.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angularjs-spring-data-jpa-crud-app-example/ I have imported this project from tutorial, it runs perfectly without any error. But for view it used index.ftl, it shows 404 error in eclipse.

my application.yml file

```
---
server:
  port: 8080
  contextPath: /SpringBootCRUDApp
---
spring:
  profiles: local, default
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/emp
    username: sa
    password: 
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 10
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: create-drop
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
datasource:
  sampleapp:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emp
    username: root
    password: root
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    defaultSchema:
    maxPoolSize: 20
    hibernate:
      hbm2ddl.method: update
      show_sql: true
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This application is a spring boot application which is like a stand alone application(it use internal tomcat), no external tomcat is required. You have to start it using maven or directly from the application class.

1. Stop any servers if you are already running.
2. In the project goto the class SpringBootCRUDApp -> rightClick -> Run as Spring Boot Application. Now, you should see the application is getting started.

Once its started, goto the browser and give this URL http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp. You should see the screen shown above.

Comment: Good Mark the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Believe that your application has started successfully.

You should use http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp ..

[image]

Comment: No unable to start application getting error 404.Are you able to start same application?
http://imgur.com/a/B0UaO

Comment: I also used above url you mentioned but getting same error

Comment: I am asking about whether your application started in console. can you send your console log screenshot and and try the below URl. SpringBootCRUDApp is defined in application.properties. http://localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp

Comment: yes in console application has started.please check this http://imgur.com/a/mGhYz. tried URI localhost:8080/SpringBootCRUDApp but also showing 404 error.

Comment: What I am missing? Do you able to run application?

Comment: why are you starting external tomcat. Do you know how this application should run? you are using wrong way of starting this application. are you using war or sourcecode to run this application?

Comment: I have run this application in eclipse. And just checking it in chrome.not using war to run this aplication. But still if I am wrong then please tell me the steps.